# Dummy variable where two continuous variables are equal in R?

Tags: r

Data set cwm looks like this

```
V1  V2  V3
1   2   ?
3   5   ?
4   4   ?
#NA 9   ?
#NA #NA ?
```

Want to create dummy variable V3, 1 if V1=V2, 0 otherwise, and producing #NA in any case where #NA is involved.

After I have done a similar thing for equivalent columns V3 and V4, to produce dummy variable V5, I need to create a continuous variable, V6, where 1 means neither V3 or V5 = 1, 2 means either V3 or V5 = 1, 3 means both V3 and V5 = 1.

```
V3  V5  V6
1   0   ?
1   0   ?
0   0   ?
1   1   ?
```

If done correctly, V3 = {0,0,1,#NA,#NA} and V6 = {2,2,1,3}

Best approach?

Comment: Please explain down voting so I can edit/avoid in future.

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you want to know how to improve it. For starters, ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text="V1  V2
1   2
3   5
4   4
NA 9
NA NA",
header = TRUE, na.strings="NA")

V3 = as.numeric(df$V1 == df$V2)
V3
[1]  0  0  1 NA NA


df2 = read.table(text="V3  V5
1   0
1   0
0   0
1   1",
header = TRUE)

V6 = df2$V3 + df2$V5 + 1
V6
[1] 2 2 1 3
```